# Torah reading for Mincha when Shemini Atzeret falls on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, torah-reading, shmini-atzeres

(This question assumes we are in the Diaspora, so that Simchat Torah is on the second day of Shemini Atzeret.)

This coming year (5784) the first day of Shemini Atzeret falls on Shabbat.  What do we read from the Torah at Shabbat Mincha?  Presumably we read the first part of Parshat *Vezot Habracha*.  But that seems weird -- we read it at Mincha, and then we read it again at Maariv for Simchat Torah?  I can't think of an alternative that seems more reasonable, but something about that just seems off to me.

Comment: It is indeed correct, weird though it may be. Last time was 2020, so it may have already been a weirder time due to COVID. The time before that was 2009, long ago enough to forget the weirdness.

Comment: Also note that reading at maariv of ST is a relatively recent custom, not observed by everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Machzor](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43077&st=&pgnum=191) instructs to read, as you speculated, from *Vezot Habracha*. I have personally never heard of any other practice in this regard.